# Gravity forms WEBAPI javascript input name with period not working

Tags: javascript, forms, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a problem with a field name that has a period `"."` to it

I can only make it work if the field name is something like `input_1 or input_1_2`

But when it is something like `input_1.2` it doesn't work.

```
function CalculateSig(stringToSign, privateKey){
    //calculate the signature needed for authentication
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(stringToSign, privateKey);
    var base64 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    return encodeURIComponent(base64);
}


var d = new Date;
var expiration = 3600; 
var unixtime = parseInt(d.getTime() / 1000);
var future_unixtime = unixtime + expiration;
var publicKey = "mupubkey";
var privateKey = "pyprikey";
var method = "POST";
var route = "forms/6/submissions";

stringToSign = publicKey + ":" + method + ":" + route + ":" + future_unixtime;
sig = CalculateSig(stringToSign, privateKey);
var url = 'https://www.localhostlbahblah.com/gravityformsapi/' + route + '?api_key=' + publicKey + '&signature=' + sig + '&expires=' + future_unixtime;

var values = {input_values:{'input_1.3':"test",// not working first name value
                                "input_2":"testetest", // this is working
                                }}

values_json = JSON.stringify(values);

$.post(url, values_json, function(data){
    console.log(data.response);
});
```

Comment: have you tried with
'input_1\.3'

Comment: Yes, but not getting through

Comment: First off, you need to use `encodeURIComponent()` around any arbitrary data used in your URL.  I doubt that's what's causing this specific issue for you though.  Where are you setting your request body content type to JSON?  What does the actual request/response over the wire look like?

Comment: this is what the json being sent  {"input_values":{"input_1.3":"Test field","input_2":"This is ok"}}:

Comment: I solved it by replacing "." with underscore input_1_3 :) thanks to everyone who pitched in. I really appreciate your help, and this community!